# Is it better to load from Bundle or disk?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiimageview, embedded-resource

I have about 10 images in my app.  They are in the bundle as resources.  Is it better to load them from the bundle on each app start?  Or deploy them to disk once and always load from disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be a little premature optimizing…

Is your app slow now?

At some point the images are coming off the disk, no matter what. If it really becomes an issue, you can implement both solutions and benchmark them with instruments.

I have built several apps with images and haven't even thought of this. I assume the difference in performance would be negligible, since, as I said, they come off disk either way.

I think the best thing to do would be to mark this down in your code as a possible optimization and just go with what you have now. When you start beta testing, if speed becomes an issue, you can try it then.